# How to print single '\' (slash) in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

My required  output is :

```
 'grep "key\":\"value" test_File.txt'
```

for example, what i tried is..

```
>>> cmd = 'grep "key\":\"value" test_File.txt'
>>> cmd
 'grep "key":"value" test_File.txt'
```

but it prints two slashes when i try to escape the actual slash.

```
>>> cmd = 'grep "key\\":\\"value" test_File.txt'
>>> cmd
 'grep "key\\":\\"value" test_File.txt'
 >>>
```

all i need is ,how can i get the first line as output ?

Comment: just `print(cmd)`. You are printing the `repr` of the string.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  This looks very much like you are trying to print a command to be executed by the shell, and being very confused about the shell's quoting rules.  A valid `grep` command would look like `grep '"key":"value"' test_File.txt` but I am second-guessing several details here.  With `subprocess` you want to avoid `shell=True` and pass just `['grep', '"key":"value"', 'test_File.txt']` instead of a string.

Comment: yeah,i am trying to pass this  as a command to subprocess to get executed ,

Comment: This isn't a real duplicate of anything, but instead a typo. OP wanted to `print` something, but wrote code that doesn't use `print`; there is nothing wrong with the actual string contents.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get the *escaped* string confused with what's actually *printed*.

```
>>> cmd = '\'grep "key\\":\\"value\" test_File.txt\''
>>> print cmd
'grep "key\":\"value" test_File.txt'
```

I believe that matches your required output.